# Did a refund just give me a bonus to my credit score?

Tags: credit-card, credit

I check credit karma notifications and I got one that my credit score just went up 3 points. Funny because the only transaction I had this month so far was an accident.

I was on a free trial subscription service that ended, so it automatically billed me 279 dollars for the year. I contacted support and they refunded me. Two days after that, I get a notification from credit karma that my score went up by 3 points and I didn't do anything.

Is it a coincidence or did somehow that refund consider me as "paying off" my credit card?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure it's due to something other than the $279 refund.  Two days is not enough time for that to take effect.  Perhaps your credit balances have changed or something else in your profile crossed some threshold.  It's hard to say for sure.

But a 3 pt. change is also fairly insignificant.  A credit score can move by quite a bit, +/- 10 or more, just due to normal monthly credit card usage.

Comment: Two days is plenty of time, depend on the timing of the next statement. If the next statement happened to come the day after the refund, it's entirely possible the resulting lower utilization would report to the bureaus and be reflected now.

Comment: just a little confusing because my balance was 0.00 the entire month and my auto pay is set for 22nd of each month